# how to set secure flag on cookies in laravel

Tags: php, security, cookies, laravel-5

I want to set secure flag for cookies data when accessing content over HTTPS.

The cookies is used on entire application so need to global configuration to secure all the cookies.

Comment: what do you mean by secure flag?

Comment: While in Core PHP when creating a cookie their is one parameter of secure which make the cookie secure. 
If the cookies is not secure then it is not encrypted.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to override the default setting using `session_set_cookie_params`, set the $secure flag to true,

```
void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )
```

more info at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

In laravel you need to alter the config/session.php configuration,set the secure flag to true

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => true,
```

In newer versions of laravel you can simply set the `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true` in the `.env` file

Comment: That line in the config file looks like this in newer versions of Laravel:
`'secure' => env( 'SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true ),`

Answer (score 40):

You can set the value of `secure` *true* in your `config/session.php` file as illustrated below;

```
'secure' => env( 'SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true ),
```

Comment: This line of code may not actually set `secure` to `true`, if the .env file contains `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false`. The second parameter passed to the `env` helper method simply sets the default to `true` and is used only if the `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` environment variable doesn't exist in the .env file.